# PHP - variables not comparing to one another

Tags: php, html, if-statement, mysqli

I am doing a password reset page for my website and when a user puts a new password on the `<form method="post" action="passVerif.php">` it goes to the PHP with this code:

Until now I cannot make the php compare the two new entered passwords to verify if they are equal or not, it simply jumps over that part.

P.S. don't mind the `$senha = md5($password)` it is like this for easy troubleshoot on localhost (MAMP).

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connectivity.php");

$user_id = $_SESSION['ResetUtilizadorID'];
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FROM usuarios WHERE id =".$user_id."");
$password = $password1;
$senha = md5($password);
$adminID = $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'];

if (strcmp($user_id,$adminID) == 0) {
$_SESSION['avisoReset'] = "not possible to change admin password.";
header('Location: ../login/reset_password.php');
} else {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($senha == $row['senha']){
        $_SESSION['avisoReset'] = "password taken";
        header('Location: ../login/reset_password.php');
    }
}
if ($password1 == $password2){
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = '".$senha."' WHERE id='".$user_id."'");
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$query) {
            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        $_SESSION['avisoReset'] = "new passoword set";
        //header('Location: ../login/reset_password.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['avisoReset'] = "Passwords not equal!";
        header('Location: ../login/reset_password.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First comment: $user_id is usually an integer. So assumming an INTEGER you don't need to add single quotes on the mysql SELECT statement `'".$user_id."'"`

Comment: Why are you doing `$_POST['password1'] !== $_POST['password2']` if you are assigning the vars above? It's not that it won't work, but you could do `$password1==$password2` instead.

Comment: Your SQL is wrong

Comment: Don't use the strict comparisson when you compare the passwords `!==`. As these are strings you don't need to check for types. Just use `!=` instead.

Comment: But still after your changes @MarkSkayff it does not redirect to the other page saying that the passwords are not equal. I had the code like this because it has bits and pieces from various sources (I am trying to learn html, php, mysql all by myself).

Comment: My SQL is not wrong because when I did not add the part of the code that compares passwords, it worked perfectly for what I wanted @Edakos so if you wouldn't mind removing the downvote, I would be pleased.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` <- What is `$query`?  Looks like the `while` is never entered.

Comment: If the passwords don't match, and that's an error scenario, I wouldn't make any DB calls.  Do your easy validation first.

Comment: `$query` is on connectivity.php @LeeKowalkowski

Comment: I will check it without DB @LeeKowalkowski to see if it is anything wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to attempt to change a password on a DB for every row from the result of `$query` where `$senha == $row['senha']` is false.  How many passwords are you updating?

Comment: Whenever I do a redirect, I usually want to stop PHP straight after.  I think `exit()` inside the `if` statement is actually cleaner than trying to nest `if/else` conditions to avoid further code from being executed.  Or writing your own redirect function that sets the header and exits PHP.

Comment: That's not changing every password on a DB, what I coded it is meant to check on the DB if there's a equal password to the one that was entered, if it was, the user is redirected with a warning, if not, continues to check to the rest of the DB, after that if it is not equal to any of the DB it changes it. @LeeKowalkowski

Comment: You shouldn't leak that knowledge to users! (unless you have a password history check and you're just denying this user from reusing one of his own old passwords)

Comment: You don't need to iterate to check if a password already exists, just look for the matching record with a SELECT's WHERE clause.  - And you're still calling the DB if the two entered passwords don't match in your updated example.  (As well as updating the password if fails the history check).

Comment: Alright! I will correct that! @LeeKowalkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a username and then comparing the user input data to the DB. So the problem of multiple users by any chance use the same password it is all good.

Comment: I know you said to ignore `$senha = md5($password);` but ideally you should [hash every user's password with a salt that is unique to that user](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing) - this will reduce the possibility of multiple users having the same hashed password in your DB, but the possibility will still not be zero, so you still need this check.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using strpos? strpos finds the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string. So the password could be a subset of another string (the stored password) and still evaluate to true for your use case.

```
if (strpos($user_id,$adminID) == true)
```

You should instead use strcmp (Binary safe string comparison):

```
if (strcmp($user_id,$adminID) == 0)
```

Comment: Already changed that! Thanks, but it does not change the output.